# Why does the BIOS perform a RAM check before booting?

Tags: boot, memory, security, bios

It appears a little arbitrary to me, so I presume there is some specific reasoning behind this. RAM failure should occur very rarely (it never has to me) and most errors will not even be caught by this test (a comprehensive check would take much longer).

If the BIOS code is not safe to rely on the RAM without verifying it first, why is OS code not checking hard drives as well? I seem to be missing something here.

Comment: Is this a RAM *test* everytime you boot, or simply the POST process?

Comment: Do you mean a full test of all RAM cells? That is not normally done by *any* OS of which I know, since it takes a *considerable* time. If that is the case, there may be an issue with your system.

Comment: *"I seem to be missing something here."* -- When the IBM PC was introduced, DRAM was not as reliable as SRAM.  (SRAM was invented about a decade before DRAM.)  Hence the memory test on boot, which as a side benefit confirmed the size of the installed DRAM.  Your personal experience of no (D)RAM failures is mostly explained by the vast improvement in DRAM technology and manufacturing since the 1980s.  *"why is OS code not checking hard drives as well?"* -- HDDs have ECC to validate the data, although  **chkdsk** could be needed .

Comment: @sawdust Sounds like an answer to me, why not post it as such? :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasaons, each sufficient by itself.

1. Just about every microcontroller- and microprocessor-based device does a POST - power-on-self-test. It's what you do.
2. The RAM test is merely one part (though the longest-duration part) of POST - Power-On Self-Test. POST verifies the presence and basic functionality of several key components of the system. If the firmware (whether BIOS or EFI) were to try to proceed with normal startup procedures if any of those components were missing or not operating correctly the problem could be extremely difficult to diagnose.
3. Contrary to your experience, a significant number of PCs, Macs, etc., do experience failures at the RAM test step.. often immediately after first assembly or after changing RAM or CPU. You are correct that there are RAM problems that this simple test won't detect, but that doesn't mean the test is pointless. Saying "oh, just run memtest" assumes that there is some way to load memtest, etc.